# Add multiple children layouts from XML file to another layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

My layout is based on what Android Studio creates - blank with an action bar. This is the default code to inflate my fragment_list.xml into activity_stats.xml (I only have one Java file)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

Activity_stats is unaltered, just like Android Studio generated it. This is fragment_list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.company.dummyname.stats$PlaceholderFragment" >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/network_margin_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/network_margin_horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/network_margin_vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/networkContainer"/>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to add multiple children to networkContainer. The children should be layouts from network.xml, which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.company.dummyname.stats$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    grid:columnCount="2" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="#fff8cdac"
        grid:layout_row="0"
        grid:layout_column="0"
        grid:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        grid:layout_row="0"
        grid:layout_column="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9999.99"
            android:id="@+id/totalToday"
            android:textSize="32sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" today"
            android:textSize="32sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        grid:layout_row="1"
        grid:layout_column="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9999.99"
            android:id="@+id/totalYesterday"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" yesterday"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        grid:layout_row="2"
        grid:layout_columnSpan="2">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                style="@style/StatsCell" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/StatsCell"
                android:text="Hits" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                style="@style/StatsCell"
                android:text="Today"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/StatsCell"
                android:id="@+id/todayHits"
                android:text="9999" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

There will be more data and one more row, but I removed them to simplify the question. The goal is to have many instances of network.xml with different data. How do I insert them and alter the data inside? I did research on Google, but without success. Please ignore the hardcoded strings and dimensions, I'll fix that.

EDIT: I need to add the children programmatically, not in XML, because the number of network.xml instances will vary depending on user settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IN XML**

To Include multiple layouts you should use [**include**](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) element in the parent layout to referring to child layouts

**IN CODE (PROGRAMATICALLY)**

In the `onCreateView` function where you get the root `View` try to get the container layout like this

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.networkContainer);
```

and then in that linear layout create and add the instances of the other views you want to add like this
to get the View for the child Layout use [LayoutInflator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

```
layout.addView(newView);
```

and finally return the parent **View**

Comment: Thanks, but I need to include the layouts programmatically, because there can be different number of networks, depending on user settings.

Comment: Welcome well you showed XML and not what you tried in Code so i shared this. Add what you have tried in Code first in the question then i will guide you

Comment: I edited the question to stress that. I need to include one or more network.xml layouts into networkContainer element in Java code. The number depends on user settings, so I can't use XML include.

Comment: One more problem: I know how to addView, but how do I get my network.xml in to newView variable?

Comment: Thanks it works now, I was using it in PlaceHolder fragment method at first, so it didn't work.